# How to store FontFamily as a StaticResource?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to figure out how to set a FontFamily in my App.xaml in such a way that I can declaratively apply that style wherever I need to.
In the `ResourceDictionary` I can apply something like:

```
<System:Double x:Key="SmallTextSize">10</System:Double>
```

What I want to do then is something like:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MainFont">Wingdings</FontFamily>
```

But, the only thing I can get to work is an implicit style, which requires a target, and multiple declarations of the font I want to use.  I need to be able to apply the style I end up with to the FontFamily property of any control.

Here's the closest I can come presently:

```
<System:String x:Key="MainFont">Wingdings</System:String>
<Style TargetType="UserControl">
      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFont}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

This implementation doesn't work on something like because it expects MainFont to be  a FontFamily, not a string:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="0,0,0,4" FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="{StaticResource MainFont}" FontSize="14.667" />
```

How should I handle this?  Thanks!

Comment: Here's a possible workaround if you don't find a more suitable answer: use an attached dependency property to set the `FontFamily`. You would then get something like: `<TextBlock FontManager.FontFamily="{StaticResource MainFont}" />`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's the exact opposite of what I'm going for.  I'm trying to consolidate styles in a VERY large Silverlight application, so applying the styles at that level would mean thousands of edits.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if you are going to be setting fonts as in your example above, that is `FontFamily="{StaticResource MainFont}"`, then it will require the exact same number of edits.

Comment: No, that is an implicit style, meaning one setting per type of object, not per object.

Comment: Do you mean `<Style TargetType="UserControl">
      <Setter Property="myns:FontManager.FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFont}"></Setter>
</Style>`?  You can apply attached properties in the implicit style as well.

Comment: The `FontManager` declaration is redundant, but yes.  That's exactly what I have above, and would accomplish the same thing.  Using what you've described is no different from how it's implemented now.

Comment: Well the difference is that your final example would work, which you claim does not work in your question above. There is a difference because `FontManager.FontFamily` is a string and can create the `FontFamily` object in the C# code when it is applied to the control.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure I entirely understand this one exactly, since what I do is;

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MainFont">WingDings</FontFamily>
```

If you're talking about then applying it to multiple instances without having to declare it to each one then I would just do like;

```
<Object>
   <Object.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource YourDefaultTextBlockStyleToInheritOtherProperties}">
         <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource MainFont}"/>
      </Style>
   </Object.Resources>

   <!-- Your FontFamily automatically gets inherited to all children of the object 
        whether your object is say a Grid, or StackPanel, 
        or even an entire UserControl -->    
   <TextBlock Text="ABCDEFG"/>
   <TextBlock Text="12345"/>
   <TextBlock Text="!()*&@#"/>

</Object>
```

Comment: I think my confusion arises from the top declaration, which gives me a warning about there being no default constructor for `FontFamily', but apparently that does work...

Comment: No default constructor? haha, um, what? Paste it on here we'll get you sorted out.

Comment: Ok, so `<FontFamily x:Key="MainFontFamily">Wingdings</FontFamily>` in my App.xaml gives me a little warning saying "No default constructor found", but, after seeing what you posted, I tried using it on a style, and lo and behold, it worked.  Go figure, no idea why VS2012 is giving me the warning.

Comment: Ah vs2012, I havent had time to run through its inevitable shortcomings, bug it on msconnect if it becomes an issues since that's what it sounds like. ;)