# Embeded Navajo Font not displaying in C# XAML App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts

I am helping develop an application to store and display songs, many of which are in the Navajo language. I have added the font into a folder called Fonts in the main directory and changed the build action to "Content".

In the app.xaml file, I added this line:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="VerdanaNavajo">Fonts/VERDN___.TTF#Verdana Navajo</FontFamily>
```

Then in the main view, I added the Font Family attribute to the text field that will be displaying the song lyrics like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row ="2" Text="{Binding CurrentSong.FirstLineOfNextVerse}" Foreground="{Binding ScreenSettings.ForegroundColor}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="{StaticResource VerdanaNavajo}" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0.4,0,19.6" Grid.RowSpan="2"></TextBlock>
```

But the lyrics still display garbled in the default font:

```
Dzi[ gh33� g00 baa da ho[ ne�,
T�11 �a[ tsog00 baa da ho[ ne�,
Dzi[ gh32� di baa da ho[ ne�,
Christ yizhch9, da doh n7.
```

Anything I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383400/how-to-store-fontfamily-as-a-staticresource? Does that address your problem?

Comment: I don't believe so. It seems like the issue on that thread is how to apply a style to all text boxes, I am just trying to get this font to work on one.